How to submit form by Ferrum::Browser without using javascript
I want to submit a form by Ferrum::Browser.
<form action="/login" method="post" name="login_form">
  <button type="submit" name="login">login</button>
</form>

Currently I'm using javascript by evaluate method.
browser = Ferrum::Browser.new
browser.evaluate('document.forms[name="login_form"].submit()')

But I want to avoid evalute JS if possible. Is there another way to submit form when the submit button is implemented by button tag instead of input.
At first I tried to use focus and click, but button node was not focusble.
browser.at_css("button[type='submit']").focus
#=> Ferrum::BrowserError: Element is not focusable


Try browser.at_css("button[type='submit']").click (no need to focus)

By click nothing visible happens in the Browser. It just returns Ferrum::Node object.

click works just fine with the code that you show. make sure button is not disabled, maybe you need to fill in the form to enable submit button. button need to be visible on screen, you should focus first .focus.click.
